# My project routes are suddenly stop to work, and php artisan route:list show there is no any route

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a web.php file like this I just uninstall the maatwebsite/excel package and run composer update. Then I got the problem

[image]

```
Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
//Email Routes
Route::match(['get','post'],'/contact', [ContactController::class,'show'])->name('contact');
Route::get('/send-contact-mail', [ContactController::class,'mail'])->name('mail');
Route::match(['get','post'],'/volunteer', [VolunteerController::class,'volunteerForm'])->name('volunteerForm');
Route::get('/news', [NewController::class,'news'])->name('news');
```

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: try php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: I tried still not working

Comment: I'd be looking for changes you might've made in `RouteServiceProvider.php`. It looks like you're using Git; have you checked the full set of changes?

Comment: Yes I am using Git, but I never change anything in RouteServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 0):

Check your config/app.php file. Maybe reference to RouteServiceProvider is missing from providers array. In that case, add it:

```
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class
```

Hope this helps! :)